# Debugging GWT generated classes

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, gwt, generator

I'm trying to debug a project that uses a GWT generator to create a class. I need to "step into" one of the methods of that class in eclipse's debug mode, but it can't find the source file (obviously).

Does anyone know of a good way to integrate GWT generators and a normal debug process (breakpoints etc.)?

I thought of outputting the classes to a specific folder and going from there, but I think GWT gives them strange names, so it wouldn't be so easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the GWT compiler option `-gen [path]` to output the generated files to a specific folder (add the option in the eclipse debug configuration in the gwt program arguments). By simply selecting this path in eclipse as the folder to look for sources you can see the sources and debug the generated files.