# Debug generated GWT classes in idea

Tags: java, gwt, intellij-idea

It was asked how to debug GWT generated classes in [eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832213/debugging-gwt-generated-classes). The same thing I need to do in Intellij Idea 13.0. I added parameter -gen  and have generated sources there, then marked this directory as sources root. Then I started GWT in dev mode from Idea, but BP in generated sources aren't reachable.

Comment: It's not what you're asking, but using SuperDevMode with source maps enabled you can step through generated classes in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks it's easy on Intellij idea. it's may be your config are wrong.

[image]

```
VM option: -Xms1024m -Xmx1024M -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m

Dev Mode parameters: -port 8083 -noserver -startupUrl /IWinDoc/frontend/index.jsp com.iwindoc.frontend.Main
```

note that you must replace port,/IWinDoc/frontend/index.jsp and com.iwindoc.frontend.Main with your app structure.